# Rails ActiveRecord query fails to find record in a class module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, module, rails-activerecord

I have a Rails class within a module

```
module Test
  class A < ActiveRecord::Base
  end
end
```

Im facing certain problems with querying the model

The following queries work just fine, conforming that the model connection to the database is perfect

```
Test::A.all.size
Test::A.first
Test::A.find(1)
```

However when I do a ActiveRecord find I get an error

```
Test::A.find(:first, :conditions => {:id => 1})

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find all Test::As with 'id': (first, {:conditions=>{:id=>1}}) (found 0 results, but was looking for 2)
```

What seems to be the problem? Is this the wrong way to query for a class inside a module?

Comment: what's your rails version ?

Comment: Rails version is 4.2

Answer (score 2):

This activerecord query format is not available, it was deprecated and dropped some time ago, for your query you could run either

```
Test::A.find(1)
```

or

```
Test::A.where(:id => 1).first
```

or

```
Test::A.find_by(:id => 1)
```

Comment: Yea that was the problem.